# Lifetime of exponential variable of a battery

Tags: probability, integration, improper-integrals, problem-solving, exponential-function

Suppose that the operating lifetime of a certain type of battery is an exponential random variable with parameter $\theta=2$ $($measured in years$)$. Find the probability that a battery of this type will have an operating lifetime of over 4 years.

My attempt:

We use $P(X\geq a+b|X\geq a)=P(X\geq a)$ $=$ $e^{-a/\theta}$

$f(t)=(1/2)e^{-t/2}$ for $t>0$ and $f(t)=0$

$P(X\geq 4|X\geq 2)=P(X\geq2+2|X\geq2)=P(X\geq2)$

$P(X\geq2)=(1/2)\int_{2}^\infty e^{-t/2}dt$

$=e^{-4/2}=e^{-2}=.13533$

I am not sure if my working is done correctly. Can someone please show me the correct working? If possible, can you show it the way I did it?

Answer (score 1):

$f(t)=(1/2)e^{-t/2}$ for $t>0$

$$P(T>4) = \int_4^{\infty} f(t) dt$$

$$P(T>4) =1- \int_0^{4} (1/2)e^{-t/2} dt$$

$$P(T>4) =1+e^{-t/2}|4,0 $$
$$P(T>4) = 1+e^{-\frac{4}{2}}-e^{0} =1+e^{-2} -1 = e^{-2} = 0.135335283$$

Comment: I do not see how you got $P(T>4) =1+e^{-t/2}|4,0 $. Where did you get the $1 +$ from? Can you show the step before that?

Comment: If you integrate an exponential function such as $\int e^{-at} = -\frac{1}{a}e^{-at}$.  Here $a = \frac{1}{2}$. It is that simple

Comment: I do not know what the confusion is.  Exponential distribution is a pdf that characterizes time until failure ( lifetime).  If you want  lifetime to be more than 4 years, it means you failure should not happen before 4 years.  Thus P(T>4) = 1-P(T<=4).  The limits indicate that. Transforms from (4 to infinity) to (0 to 4). (0-4) is nothing but the CDF. It should be very clear.  I really do not know how else I could explain it to you

Comment: Diregard my last comment. I needed to delete that one. Sorry. Somehow it had a lag time of posting. Must of been my connection.